# Remove all web textual content keeping only HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Need to strip all web content from html file keeping only HTML Tags.

Could it be done by Regular Expression OR JavaScript ?

**BEFORE :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ask a Question - Stack Overflow</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Code remains un-touched");
</script>
</head>
<body class="ask-page new-topbar">
<div id="first">ONE</div>
<div id="sec">TWO</div>
<div id="third">THREE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**AFTER :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Code remains un-touched");
</script>
</head>
<body class="ask-page new-topbar">
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="sec"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE :** Need to work with later HTML tags, after stripping web-content, the html should be displayed. In the end, i am interested in the HTML Code.

Comment: You need check that each element has content or not if yes remove it,

Comment: Tool can be anything.

Comment: @j08691 : By any means, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

A simple recursive function would work:

```
(function removeTextNodes(el) {
  Array.apply([], el.childNodes).forEach(function (child) {
    if (child.nodeType === 3 && el.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') {
      // remove the text node
      el.removeChild(child);
    }
    else if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      // call recursive for child nodes
      removeTextNodes(child);
    }
  });
})(document.documentElement);
```

Quoting Amadan: just use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to get the html as a string.

Comment: yes it is correct, but i want the html code, not the rendered html !

Comment: But it is not working for this HTML source code : http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00009R6X9 HTML is overridden. HTML DOM should be un-touched. also @Amadan

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking something like this should work:

```
$('*').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.parentNode.nodeName != 'SCRIPT';
  }).remove();
});
```

Iterate over all elements, see all their child nodes, if they're text nodes and not inside `script`, kill 'em.

You can test on this very page :P

(Yoshi's jQueryless script is faster, but this was shorter to write :P )

EDIT: `nodeName` is in caps. Oops.

EDIT for OP's edit: This will subsequently fetch the source code:

```
$('html')[0].outerHTML
```

and you can display it using:

```
$('body').text($('html')[0].outerHTML)
```

EDIT again: Also, if you want it jQueryless, you can also do `document.documentElement.outerHTML` instead (which is both faster *and* nicer). Works with Yoshi's solution, too.

Comment: Looks good, let me test it on some html's, with regards to requirement, i'll get back to you. :)